# How literally does SU take "not about a shopping or buying recommendation"?

Tags: discussion, site-definition

I fully support the clause of the SU FAQ that states that shopping/buying recommendations are off-topic. I'm a little confused about its scope, though.

Does it apply to questions that ask people to suggest free, open-source applications? That's not technically buying, but it's equivalent to a shopping/buying rec for a person with a budget of $0.

What about recommendation questions where the OP doesn't mention cost at all?

(I reflexively tried to apply the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to this question, but that obviously has its own special meaning here. Is there a tag for posts about `superuser.com/faq`?)

EDIT:
Here are a few example questions:

- https://superuser.com/questions/220065/free-software-for-learning-arabic-language
- [FOSS alternatives to Acrobat Connect Pro](https://superuser.com/questions/107641/foss-alternatives-to-acrobat-connect-pro)
- https://superuser.com/questions/244853/what-is-the-best-free-software-to-learn-touch-typing
- https://superuser.com/questions/190958/do-you-know-a-free-screen-recorder-that-records-3d-applications-fluently
- [Are there programs that convert PowerPoint block diagrams to ASCII text diagrams?](https://superuser.com/questions/122199/are-there-programs-that-convert-powerpoint-block-diagrams-to-ascii-text-diagrams)

There are plenty of these under [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) and [free](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/free). (In fact, those tags have an intersection of [sixteen questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/free+software-rec).)

Comment: can you provide some examples of such questions?

Comment: @Jeff, I asked this question after seeing a few examples, but didn't save the URLs. I'll keep an eye out, though.

Comment: Though we've had shopping recommendations are not allowed clause in FAQ - I've never seen this being applied to software. Guess more so because most of [software-rec](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) questions generally ask for free/OSS

Comment: I, for one, would like to get some free, open-source hardware. PLZSUGEST!!!

Comment: [Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/) ;) @LordT

Comment: @Sathya, heh, well-played (if not strictly literally accurate).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Shopping suggestions will be closed **almost every time**. However there is a tactful way in approaching a question when it come to purchases.

For example, instead of asking what **IS** the best *product* a better question would be "What technologies should be considered when purchasing a certain *product*. For example, I wanted to know more about [laptop batteries](https://superuser.com/questions/203186/laptop-battery-technology) since mine died. I didn't want to know about which battery was better than the another, but rather prompted for more information regarding what to look for in a good battery.

If anyone asks specifically for the how's, or the what's needed about specific devices relating to PC's and their hardware  then the question will most likely not be closed, and more importantly, the OP will get a great answer to what they are *really* looking for.

Software (as you present for your examples) are somewhat of a gray area, as most software recommendations and/or the OP's desire is open-source. However, the same rule applies that if the questions are asking for "What's the best 'foo' software?" It will be closed. No matter if it's open-source or paid.

This is the main root, in my opinion, as to why shopping questions are so strictly monitored and closed. These type of questions bring no growth to the OP or the general public, but is rather just "fluff" that Super User and Stack Exchange will not be a part of.

I suggest following the same criterion when asking, editing, or voting to close when it comes to software/hardware recommendations:

- Does the question ask for specifics?
- Can a voice of opinion be backed up with hard facts?
- Does the question ask "What's the best" instead of "How do I" or "Is there? " or "What do I need to know about". (Note that these aren't always the best either but I think you get the point)
- Will answering/asking this question further my/others understanding of the topic at hand?

Answer (score 6):

Shopping recommendations are normally **off-topic** because they have an extremely narrow scope where they would apply. Everyone has different requirements.

Suggesting free or open source applications would be along the same vein.

Answer (score 6):

> Does it apply to questions that ask people to suggest free, open-source applications? That's not technically buying, but it's equivalent to a shopping/buying rec for a person with a budget of $0.

I would say in general, yes it does -- the principle is not to recommend specific products, but to teach how to evaluate them technically.

(It is also very much OK to make specific recommendations *along with the teaching* but the teaching part has to be there. The worst case scenario is a link to a product; the best case scenario is a detailed explanation of how to evaluate, plus the pros and cons of several currently available options.)

Still, it depends on the question; did you have any specific ones you can link to.

Comment: I updated my post with a few examples, and I just came across [this](http://superuser.com/questions/247002/where-can-i-find-windows-proxy-filter-software-for-a-network-non-desktop-machin) and [this](http://superuser.com/questions/246992/suggestion-for-a-good-free-video-editor) a few moments ago. You and KronoS both said pretty much exactly what I expected and wanted, though. At this point, I'm down to deciding which of your answers to accept. (Well, that, and which close reason to use; all but "exact dupe" seem to apply.)

Comment: @lord no contest, Kronos answer is way better!

Answer (score 2):

Software recommendations tend to pass because they're often 'how' to do things rather than a straight off "What do I need?". Shopping recommendations are bad because firstly, they go stale (software doesn't in most cases), and they indicate a certain lack of homework.

I can dust off a two year old software rec question, and most of the software there would still be available in some fashion. I can't really say the same for hardware, if the answer is specific enough.

I'd note I'm ['guilty'](https://superuser.com/search?q=user:10165%20%5Bsoftware-rec%5D%20is:question&submit=search) of a few software rec questions, but generally they're useful/obscure bits of software, and they apparently don't exist (yet). [In the one situation where the software](https://superuser.com/questions/128648/alternatives-to-altaris-symantec-svs) *was* found, it was useful in at least 2-3 other questions.

I'd say a properly asked software question is nothing like a hardware rec question.

Comment: Regarding lack of homework, every time I run into a question like this it's because I have done extensive homework regarding a product that meets my requirements, haven't found one, and am hoping that I have just missed something.